# Auto move to second line in a Table

Tags: tables

Is there a way to auto make content in a table to second line?

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for column headers
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


 \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lllll}
     \toprule
    \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Reference} & \textbf{Note} \\
     \midrule
    1998 & \textit{Computer Science Branch} & Herrera et al., 2004 & codingnot working and  no further update since 1998  \\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
    
    
    
\end {document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a fixed width column specifier for the last solumn, e.g.  the `X` column type:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx, threeparttable}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for column headers
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}    

 \begin{table}[h!]
 \centering \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lllX}
     \toprule
    \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Reference} & \textbf{Note} \\
     \midrule
    1998 & \textit{Computer Science Branch} & Herrera et al., 2004 & coding not working and no further update since 1998 \\
  \bottomrule
 \end{tabularx}
 \end{table}

\end {document}
```

[image]